# WSO2 ESB Show response in Tryit console

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Hi I am using WSO2 ESB I have created a proxy named "query" its work get data from salesforce and insert into mssql database table, but I want to show that response in right response area

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="query"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <salesforce.init>
            <username>$USER$</username>
            <password>$PASSWORD$$TOKEN$</password>
            <loginUrl>https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/27.0</loginUrl>
         </salesforce.init>
         <salesforce.queryAll>
            <batchSize>200</batchSize>
            <queryString>select  Id,name,Account.name,AssistantName,AssistantPhone,Birthdate,CreatedBy.name,Department,Description,Email,HomePhone,LastModifiedBy.Name,MobilePhone,Title from Contact</queryString>
         </salesforce.queryAll>
         <sequence key="generatebatch"/>
         <iterate xmlns:sfdc="http://wso2.org/salesforce/adaptor"
                  expression="//sfdc:iterator">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <salesforce.queryMore>
                     <batchSize>200</batchSize>
                  </salesforce.queryMore>
                  <sequence key="generatebatch"/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </iterate>
         <respond/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>$1</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.response"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace your call DSS to payload examples for debug.

In your situation - you do iterate and send messages to endpoint, but don't do agregate mediator after iterate.